# Is it possible to alter the calorific value of cycling in Samsung Health App

Tags: samsung

I am using **Samsung Health** as a central point for my weight, food, sleep, blood pressure and exercise.

I note that if I record my **exercycle** sessions, Samsung's calorie value is twice what the exercycle says.  I believe the latter.  At present, I am entering half the time I spend on the exercycle, which is not ideal

Is it possible to tell the Samsung Health App, the true calorie value for the exercycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there is an exercycle icon.  It snot visible as yoou can only have 3 of the,  To enable it

1. Press **Exercise**
2. Press the Menu icon (horizontal lines)
3. Unselect one of the 3 that are selected (yellow star)
4. Select **Exercise bike**

Unfortunately, this too gives double the actual kcal figure.  For instance, a **1 hour** exercise shows as **521 kcal**, which is a ludicrous figure.

**I finally heard back from Samsung Health App support and there is no way to change its value.**